# Does the proof of uniqueness of a solution depend on a proof that the solution is actually a solution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

To prove: The equation $a + x = b$ has the unique solution $x = b - a$

The proof I am looking at has two parts.

There is at first the proof that $x = b - a$ solves the equation by plugging it into the equation and after some steps using the axioms of addition arriving at equivalence.

The second part is a proof of the uniqueness of the solution showing that any $y$ with $a + y = b$ is equal to $b - a$. It subtracts $a$ from each side and arrives at equivalence.

I think that the second part does prove both parts, that $x=b-a$ is a solution and that it is unique. My argument is that it finds a solution for arbitrary y with $a + y = b$, namely $b - a$, so that we can see that $x = b - a$ is a solution.

I like that there are two parts and think that proving existence is not a bad start for proving uniqueness, but in this example it just feels like something is proven twice.

Comment: The second part shows that any solution must be of that form, while the first part shows that anything of that form is a solution. Both are needed. Just because we know any solutions must be of a given form doesn't imply we know any solutions actually exist; perhaps none exist at all.

Comment: Toy example: Consider any solution to $x^2 = -1$ over the real numbers. We can say that any solution must satisfy $x < 0$ since the square of a non-negative is non-negative. This is a necessary condition, but is obviously not sufficient; no solutions exist here. We can prove things that a solution would have to satisfy, but that doesn't mean anything actually satisfies those conditions

Comment: An alternative way to prove uniqueness is to show that there is *at most one* solution, by showing that if $y_0$ and $y_1$ are both solutions, then $y_0=y_1$: for you would have $a+y_0=b=a+y_1$. So you can deduce that $a+y_0=a+y_1$ (both are equal to $b$), and subtracting $a$ from both sides you get $y_0=y_1$. So *if* there is a solution, then the solution is unique.

Comment: Yes, solving $a+y=b$ doesnt mean that a solution exist.  Heres an example:  Prove $x^{x^{x^{....}}} = 2$ has unique positive solution $x=\sqrt 2$.  Let $y$ solve $y^{y^{y^{...}}} = 2$. The $\color{blue}y^2 = \color{blue}y^{y^{y^{y^{...}}}} = y^{y^{y^{...}}}=2$. So take the square root of both sides and we get $y =\sqrt 2$.  But note, that didn't prove that a solution *exists* in the first place.... and note: no solution *does* exist.  And thirdly note $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{...}}} \ne 2$.  $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{...}}}$ is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no. As soon as you say let $y$ solve $a+y=b$, you're assuming existence, and therefore you can't also be proving it.

This is sometimes hard to see because these vector space proofs are so elementary. But say I told you to prove that for any $A,\;b$, $A$ invertible, any solution to $Ax=b$ was of the form $x=A^{-1}b$? If you were a beginner to linear algebra and I said let $x$ be a solution to $Ax=b$. Then $A^{-1}Ax=A^{-1}b$, so $x=A^{-1}b$, you'd pull me up on assuming existence.