# Is finding an equivalent form of an equation before proving something about it a correct and common approach?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a follow-up question to: [Does the proof of uniqueness of a solution depend on a proof that the solution is actually a solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3722790/does-the-proof-of-uniqueness-of-a-solution-depend-on-a-proof-that-the-solution-i)

I want to prove both existence and uniqueness of the solution $x = b - a$ for the equation $a + x = b$.

Here is a proof sketch:

1)
$a + x = b$ (i) is equivalent to $x = b - a$ (ii)

Proof omitted.

2)
$x = b - a$ is a solution for (ii)

Proof: $b - a = b - a$

Because of equivalence, it is also a solution for (i).

This proves existence of the solution.

3)
Let us assume a number $x1$ exists with $x1 = b - a$. Then because $x = b- a$, we see that $x1 = x$.

This proves uniqueness of the solution.

Comment: In some (more complicated) cases we cannot prove the existence of a solution. But this does not rule out that we can prove the uniqueness. If we can show $x=y$ , if $x$ and $y$ are solutions (even if we do not know whether there is such a solution), we have proven the uniqueness.

Comment: This reminds me of the induction step. For some examples the induction step could hold even if the base case does not hold.